# Application error - react on heroku using heroku CLI

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I have a react application on Heroku using Heroku CLI. I am having the above error, I tried to use express but I am getting the same error below are the app logs.
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command

```
2022-05-16T08:55:02.550978+00:00 app[web.1]: 16: 0xfb02ff v8::internal::JsonStringify(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T08:55:02.551498+00:00 app[web.1]: 17: 0xd7afe7 v8::internal::Builtin_JsonStringify(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T08:55:02.552256+00:00 app[web.1]: 18: 0x15f2179  [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T08:55:02.570287+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=self-onboarding.herokuapp.com request_id=248575c3-c610-4953-97a1-407283c4db4e fwd="102.70.3.151" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5290ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2022-05-16T08:55:02.785981+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-05-16T08:55:02.837841+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2022-05-16T08:55:02.841880+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-05-16T08:55:12.496939+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-05-16T08:55:13.481913+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-05-16T08:55:13.481929+00:00 app[web.1]: > self-onboarding@0.1.0 start
2022-05-16T08:55:13.481929+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2022-05-16T08:55:13.481929+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-05-16T08:55:15.505089+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:29) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onAfterSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
2022-05-16T08:55:15.505108+00:00 app[web.1]: (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
2022-05-16T08:55:15.505273+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:29) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_BEFORE_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onBeforeSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
2022-05-16T08:55:15.736569+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-05-16T08:55:16.156311+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2022-05-16T08:55:16.156318+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-05-16T08:55:47.046333+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=self-onboarding.herokuapp.com request_id=28dc9197-4df4-48b4-96f0-ef9dc2044c06 fwd="102.70.3.151" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2022-05-16T08:55:47.514922+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=self-onboarding.herokuapp.com request_id=2bfd0032-06cd-41a5-a33c-31e21ea23794 fwd="102.70.3.151" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2022-05-16T08:55:55.055171+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-05-16T08:55:55.055178+00:00 app[web.1]: <--- Last few GCs --->
2022-05-16T08:55:55.055179+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-05-16T08:55:55.055193+00:00 app[web.1]: [29:0x67096c0]    40698 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 250.9 (258.1) -> 250.7 (258.8) MB, 90.0 / 0.1 ms  (+ 96.0 ms in 28 steps since start of marking, biggest step 8.4 ms, walltime since start of marking 195 ms) (average mu = 0.265, current mu = 0.107) allocati[29:0x67096c0]    41509 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 251.7 (258.8) -> 251.6 (259.8) MB, 809.5 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.112, current mu = 0.002) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
2022-05-16T08:55:55.055194+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-05-16T08:55:55.055194+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-05-16T08:55:55.055194+00:00 app[web.1]: <--- JS stacktrace --->
2022-05-16T08:55:55.055195+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-05-16T08:55:55.055201+00:00 app[web.1]: FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
2022-05-16T08:55:55.055972+00:00 app[web.1]: 1: 0xb09c10 node::Abort() [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T08:55:55.056566+00:00 app[web.1]: 2: 0xa1c193 node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T08:55:55.057233+00:00 app[web.1]: 3: 0xcf8dbe v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T08:55:55.057877+00:00 app[web.1]: 4: 0xcf9137 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T08:55:55.058607+00:00 app[web.1]: 5: 0xeb09d5  [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T08:55:55.059344+00:00 app[web.1]: 6: 0xec069d v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T08:55:55.060084+00:00 app[web.1]: 7: 0xec339e v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T08:55:55.060964+00:00 app[web.1]: 8: 0xe84612 v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRaw(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T08:55:55.061696+00:00 app[web.1]: 9: 0xe7cc24 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::AllocateRawWithImmortalMap(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::Map, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T08:55:55.062413+00:00 app[web.1]: 10: 0xe7ec81 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewRawTwoByteString(int, v8::internal::AllocationType) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T08:55:55.063256+00:00 app[web.1]: 11: 0x125a28c v8::internal::IncrementalStringBuilder::Extend() [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T08:55:55.064023+00:00 app[web.1]: 12: 0xfa8f90 v8::internal::JsonStringifier::SerializeString(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T08:55:55.064816+00:00 app[web.1]: 13: 0xfae4ad v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_<false>(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T08:55:55.065632+00:00 app[web.1]: 14: 0xfac930 v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_<true>(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T08:55:55.066353+00:00 app[web.1]: 15: 0xfae9e1 v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_<false>(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T08:55:55.067131+00:00 app[web.1]: 16: 0xfb02ff v8::internal::JsonStringify(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T08:55:55.067873+00:00 app[web.1]: 17: 0xd7afe7 v8::internal::Builtin_JsonStringify(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T08:55:55.068808+00:00 app[web.1]: 18: 0x15f2179  [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T08:55:55.217644+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-05-16T08:55:55.268337+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2022-05-16T08:56:16.403572+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=self-onboarding.herokuapp.com request_id=a7b524ea-2aae-4b2c-ae42-80b89497dd7d fwd="102.70.3.151" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-05-16T08:56:17.349980+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=self-onboarding.herokuapp.com request_id=347cad30-fc69-4e8f-a9d4-5e45fe962a37 fwd="102.70.3.151" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-05-16T09:00:53.075164+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=self-onboarding.herokuapp.com request_id=ac6a2c7a-1cce-4449-a464-25cab7681565 fwd="102.70.3.151" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-05-16T09:00:53.831097+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=self-onboarding.herokuapp.com request_id=fff56ae2-fe34-471d-a8f0-320ca1f4e745 fwd="102.70.3.151" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-05-16T09:01:30.332581+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-05-16T09:01:41.508890+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-05-16T09:01:43.119810+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-05-16T09:01:43.119821+00:00 app[web.1]: > self-onboarding@0.1.0 start
2022-05-16T09:01:43.119822+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2022-05-16T09:01:43.119822+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-05-16T09:01:45.569739+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:29) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onAfterSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
2022-05-16T09:01:45.569747+00:00 app[web.1]: (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
2022-05-16T09:01:45.569897+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:29) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_BEFORE_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onBeforeSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
2022-05-16T09:01:45.836777+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-05-16T09:01:45.942058+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2022-05-16T09:01:45.942065+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-05-16T09:02:18.422977+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=self-onboarding.herokuapp.com request_id=af4fa08f-e7ed-484e-b315-dd88219479ba fwd="102.70.3.151" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2022-05-16T09:02:23.732656+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-05-16T09:02:23.732664+00:00 app[web.1]: <--- Last few GCs --->
2022-05-16T09:02:23.732664+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-05-16T09:02:23.732666+00:00 app[web.1]: [29:0x691a6c0]    39573 ms: Scavenge 249.4 (257.8) -> 249.3 (258.6) MB, 0.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.340, current mu = 0.094) allocation failure
2022-05-16T09:02:23.732667+00:00 app[web.1]: [29:0x691a6c0]    40363 ms: Mark-sweep 250.3 (258.6) -> 250.2 (258.6) MB, 789.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.155, current mu = 0.015) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
2022-05-16T09:02:23.732668+00:00 app[web.1]: [29:0x691a6c0]    40538 ms: Mark-sweep 251.1 (258.6) -> 251.1 (260.6) MB, 173.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.126, current mu = 0.006) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
2022-05-16T09:02:23.732668+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-05-16T09:02:23.732674+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-05-16T09:02:23.732674+00:00 app[web.1]: <--- JS stacktrace --->
2022-05-16T09:02:23.732674+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-05-16T09:02:23.732675+00:00 app[web.1]: FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
2022-05-16T09:02:23.733306+00:00 app[web.1]: 1: 0xb09c10 node::Abort() [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T09:02:23.733777+00:00 app[web.1]: 2: 0xa1c193 node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T09:02:23.734273+00:00 app[web.1]: 3: 0xcf8dbe v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T09:02:23.734777+00:00 app[web.1]: 4: 0xcf9137 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T09:02:23.735361+00:00 app[web.1]: 5: 0xeb09d5  [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T09:02:23.735941+00:00 app[web.1]: 6: 0xec069d v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T09:02:23.736521+00:00 app[web.1]: 7: 0xec339e v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T09:02:23.737090+00:00 app[web.1]: 8: 0xe84612 v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRaw(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T09:02:23.737693+00:00 app[web.1]: 9: 0xe7cc24 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::AllocateRawWithImmortalMap(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::Map, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T09:02:23.738258+00:00 app[web.1]: 10: 0xe7ec81 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewRawTwoByteString(int, v8::internal::AllocationType) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T09:02:23.738939+00:00 app[web.1]: 11: 0x125a28c v8::internal::IncrementalStringBuilder::Extend() [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T09:02:23.739541+00:00 app[web.1]: 12: 0xfa8f90 v8::internal::JsonStringifier::SerializeString(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T09:02:23.740153+00:00 app[web.1]: 13: 0xfae4ad v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_<false>(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T09:02:23.740766+00:00 app[web.1]: 14: 0xfac930 v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_<true>(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T09:02:23.741390+00:00 app[web.1]: 15: 0xfae9e1 v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_<false>(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T09:02:23.742018+00:00 app[web.1]: 16: 0xfb02ff v8::internal::JsonStringify(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T09:02:23.742599+00:00 app[web.1]: 17: 0xd7afe7 v8::internal::Builtin_JsonStringify(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T09:02:23.743368+00:00 app[web.1]: 18: 0x15f2179  [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2022-05-16T09:02:23.762815+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=self-onboarding.herokuapp.com request_id=0e1f927f-25d1-4e16-873d-1ab0c94763dc fwd="102.70.3.151" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2817ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2022-05-16T09:02:23.902182+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-05-16T09:02:23.986214+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2022-05-16T09:03:06.677261+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=self-onboarding.herokuapp.com request_id=8b1a0c0a-5c02-4b74-a016-e3fa8c1201c7 fwd="102.70.3.151" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-05-16T09:03:07.510011+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=self-onboarding.herokuapp.com request_id=e0808892-addb-4bcb-b918-66a3bc7e0196 fwd="102.70.3.151" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Below is my express config file

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: It looks like you're using the dev server in production - it's not designed for that. See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment.

Comment: I am using node express see the edited question

Comment: Are you sure you are? It shows `react-scripts start` in the logs you've posted.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, Thank you a lot that was a problem indeed I have updated the *application.json* to use express

Comment: You must check out [This answer!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48357132).